# Django unable to create instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

so I am trying to problematically create instances but I keep getting this error. The error occurs on the last line rec.save() while I try to makemigrations. It works fine without rec.save() line.
I have tried Users.objects.create_user(username="xy",password="password123") and also flushing the database having taken out the rec.save() line.

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: catalog_company.modif
ied_by_id

here is my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
from datetime import date
import datetime
from django.urls import reverse #Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL 
patterns
from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords
from simple_history import register

register(User, inherit=True)


class Company(models.Model):
"""
Model representing a company invested in.
"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

    #details
    group=models.CharField(max_length=15, default='EQD')
    stake = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    partners = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    #user details
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='Project_modified_by')
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    #to keep records
    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return self.name

    def get_form_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access the form to change model attributes.
        """
        return reverse('forms', args=[str(self.id)])

    def attrsetter(self,attr,value):
         """
         set attribute of an instance
         """
         return setattr(self, attr, value)

    @property
    def _history_user(self): #to track who modified
        return self.modified_by

    @_history_user.setter  #to track what was modified
    def _history_user(self, value):
        self.modified_by = value


rec = Company(name='ABC',modified_date=datetime.datetime.now().date())
rec.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it. I had to have created a superuser called "admin" first.

Then according to my code modified_by field is not null so i need to give a user to it. The following works

```
adminuser = User.objects.get(username='admin')
rec = Company(name='ABC',modified_date=datetime.datetime.now().date(),modified_by= adminuser)
rec.save()
```

But this brings up another issue that everytime the code is run, it creates another instance.
createsuperuser
makemigrations
migrate
runserver..
so need to put in the appropriate if clause